# Translate SmartPy expression into Michelson

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, michelson, taquito

```
import smartpy as sp

def logic(data):
    t = sp.TRecord(x=sp.TNat, y=sp.TNat, z=sp.TNat)
    unpacked = sp.unpack(data, t).open_some(message="Can't unpack!!")
    
    sp.result(unpacked.x + unpacked.y)
    
i_need_this = sp.build_lambda(logic)
```

How will I be able to convert SmartPy functions into Michelson code?

**Context**: I need this lambda in michelson so that I am able to pass it as an argument to an entrypoint in typescript (with taquito).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-paste the answer given on Telegram.

**Using the CLI**:

```
scenario.show(lambda x:x+1, compile=True)
```

This creates a file *when called from the CLI* with the compilation target (named something like `step_000_expression.tz`).

**Using the web browser**:

```
import smartpy as sp

class MyContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init()

    @sp.entry_point
    def f(self, p):
        sp.compute(p)

@sp.add_test(name = "Test")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    c1 = MyContract()
    scenario += c1
    c1.f(lambda x:x+1)
```

(the sp.compute is almost irrelevant, it’s only there to avoid SmartPy complaining that p is unused)

Example [here](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJxVj0ELwjAMhe_9FcFTi1LQozAQPHvzXmLXQWFtwxJh@_e2YxPNIaTv5X00MVGZBDjhJLQAMjAp5UdkhsdyL1km9KKZ7D6bq4JafRjAuZijOKc5jMOmt2pP2yxtVm1tt8oIFbE4KjHLFzKs6RPQL4CsL4neEjQZpVTLYt87CSw6Ywrd4VnHg1GNsKpbmn3IOMUCXYM0x@3S9hl_rt7PaeY_d@zqxrZoBz1ievUI83U@XswHk7RZ7A--).

With a longer function you can do

```
def my_function(params):
    sp.set_type(params, sp.TRecord(a=sp.TNat, b=sp.TNat, c=sp.TNat))
    sp.result(params.a + params.b + params.c)

c1.f(my_function)
```

Example [here](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJxVjzGLxCAQhXt_hWyl7BK49iBwcPVdsWwvs2YCQtTBmRT596fB7GUt5M0b38czRMpFNEcoQpsG1kxK@QWY9c_2nZMU8GKYhkPbT6XrmXDWzoUUxDnDuMzdb6eNQ1sZu3v79VUZWBGboxySvCDznr5pOgNo8DnSKmjIKqVaFqbJCbKYBBHHy6PKi1WNsLs9zR4TlJD12CBt4w6rl_EfdXf6mn3PXcf64lUubm5ek5eQkyEoEPm9JaM42Qj78ta8xx19LpOBsQ2_IDf9_Jf@kNaeQQV5XaRjBrh28TyEP8oPszmVsn8874mK).